# How to make a binary mask out of an image with a transparent background?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation

I have a basic OpenCV question. I have an image with a transparent background and I want to create a binary mask of that image with a transparent region as black and the object as white. Can you please guide me how to start with this task or share a code snippet, that will be really helpful. 
The image is:

[image: Image with transparent background]

What I want to achieve is the binary mask, with a transparent region as black and the object being white. 
i.e.

[image: Binary Mask of the image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take the alpha channel and apply threshold (at whatever level you consider transparent enough).

Answer (score 6):

Here is one way to do that in Python/OpenCV.

- Read the input as unchanged (to keep the alpha channel)
- Extract the alpha channel
- Threshold the alpha channel
- Save the results

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load image with alpha channel
img = cv2.imread('object.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

# extract alpha channel
alpha = img[:, :, 3]

# threshold alpha channel
alpha = cv2.threshold(alpha, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# save output
cv2.imwrite('object_alpha.png', alpha)

# Display various images to see the steps
cv2.imshow('alpha',alpha)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:

[image]